# Removing data from a variable

Tags: javascript

I have a variable which carries information but i want to be able to remove the information some how.

I tried to set the .length = 0 but that didn't seem to work...

The current data of the variable (example data is):

```
var data = {"1":{"7":["310"],"22":["309"]}}
```

In english that is:

```
var data = {"X":{"Y":["ID"],"Y":["ID"]}}
```

So if i wanted to remove:

```
X: 1 Y : 22
```

The result of data would be:

```
var data = {"1":{"7":["310"]}};
```

This is what i tried:

```
data[X][Y].length = 0;
```

But that doesn't seem to work, any one understand how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
js> var data = {"1":{"7":["310"],"22":["309"]}}
js> data
({1:{7:["310"], 22:["309"]}})
js> delete data[1][22]
true
js> data
({1:{7:["310"]}})
```

Comment: Thanks thats the function i was  looking for :) is there a similiar function to "add" or would i have to look the data to add to it (which is currently how i do it but if theres a adding function that would strip some code chunks down :)

Comment: No; "adding" is already implemented via assigning, so there's no quick way (unless you find the JavaScript equivalent of [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)).

Comment: Ah so my loop to "push" to it is the only way to do it ?